# SQL: Finding Out All School Transitions Between A Range of Years

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table :

```
  student_id   school year
1          1 School A 2010
2          1 School A 2011
3          2 School C 2010
4          2 School A 2011
5          3 School B 2015
```

I wrote this query that looks at how many times a student changes their school over all available years:

```
SELECT school_count, COUNT(*) AS student_id_count
FROM
    (SELECT student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT school) AS school_count
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY student_id) AS subquery
GROUP BY school_count;
```

**My Question:** In my table, the earliest available year for any student is 2010 and the latest possible year is 2020. I want to find out:

- Between 2010-2011 : how many students changed their school 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, etc.
- Between 2010-2012: how many students changed their school 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, etc.
- Between 2010-2013: how many students changed their school 1 time, 2 times, 3 times, etc.

Currently, I am doing this manually for each combination by adding a WHERE statement:

```
WITH filtered_data AS (
    SELECT student_id, school, year
    FROM my_table
    WHERE year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2013
)
SELECT school_count, COUNT(*) AS student_id_count
FROM
    (SELECT student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT school) AS school_count
    FROM filtered_data
    GROUP BY student_id) AS subquery
GROUP BY school_count;
```

But is there a better way to do this for all possible year combinations?

Thanks!

**Note:** For the situation where you want to only look at students who were there for some specific years:

```
WITH filtered_data AS (
    SELECT student_id, school, year,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN year IN (2010, 2011, 2017, 2019) THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id) AS year_count
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT school_count, COUNT(*) AS student_id_count
FROM
    (SELECT student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT school) AS school_count
    FROM filtered_data
    WHERE year_count = 4
    GROUP BY student_id) AS subquery
GROUP BY school_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this without manually writing separate queries for each year combination by using conditional aggregation. With conditional aggregation, you can create multiple counts for different year ranges within a single query. Here's how you can do it:

```
WITH year_combinations AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.year AS year_start, b.year AS year_end
  FROM my_table a
  CROSS JOIN my_table b
  WHERE a.year <= b.year
),
filtered_data AS (
  SELECT student_id, school, year
  FROM my_table
  WHERE year BETWEEN 2010 AND 2020 -- Adjust the range as needed
)
SELECT yc.year_start, yc.year_end, school_count, COUNT(*) AS student_id_count
FROM year_combinations yc
JOIN (
  SELECT fd.student_id, COUNT(DISTINCT fd.school) AS school_count
  FROM filtered_data fd
  GROUP BY fd.student_id
) AS subquery ON subquery.school_count = yc.year_end - yc.year_start + 1
GROUP BY yc.year_start, yc.year_end, school_count
ORDER BY yc.year_start, yc.year_end, school_count;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer just a question - is my original approach (see notes) correct? Thank you so much!